# Is the installation of Pig,Hive,Hbase,Oozie,Zookeeper same in Hadoop 2.0 as in Hadoop 1.0?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig, oozie

I recently installed hadoop v_2 with the YARN Configuration. I am planning to install Hadoop ecosystem stack such as Pig,Hive,Hbase,Oozie,Zookeeper etc. I would like to know if I should install the tools from the same link that I did for Hadoop 1.0 Configuration. If not, Could anyone please send me the link for the Hadoop 2 Configuration for these tools ?. I heard that Pig and Hive are more faster in Hadoop 2.0. Therefore would like to know if there are better versions.

Thanks,
Gautham

Comment: You can consider installing with Cloudera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_16_2.html 
this may be useful 
also i think that the configuration isn't different from v 1